# Which tense is “he was not to enter into ...”

Tags: grammar, meaning

“There was one caveat: **he was not to enter** into it a merger or otherwise weaken the Roche family's control of the firm.”

I know that was is the past tense of the verb to be, but in the above sentence it has infinitive after “was not” - and that infinitive is “to enter”.
Also, I don't understand what this sentence actually means.

Comment: the verb be + to + infinitive is an idiom. It means: be supposed to, here, in the negative. He was not [supposed] to enter